# How do I make a hover effect that affects the next sibling element as well?

Tags: html, css

How can I make this hover effect with CSS and HTML?:

Normal view:

```
---------
Link-1
---------
Link-2
---------
Link-3
---------
```

When I hover Link-1, the top and bottom line change color, something like this:

```
=========
Link-1
=========
Link-2
---------
Link-3
---------
```

And if I hover Link-2 these 2 lines change:

```
---------
Link-1
=========
Link-2
=========
Link-3
---------
```

And so on...

The "====" is just indicating the change of color, not double lines
I am actually pretty lost on this one, but this is what i got so far:

```
<div id="nav">

                <a href="#" class="dummy">Link-1</a>
                <a href="#" class="dummy">Link-2</a>
                <a href="#" class="dummy">Link-3</a>

</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#nav{
    width: 200px;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: red;
}
#nav a{
    display: block;
    width: 190px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-top: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
}
#nav a:hover  {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This is the best way I can think of doing it in pure CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/6CV7B/3).

## HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 2</li>
    <li>Link 3</li>
</ul>
```

## CSS

```css
li
{
    padding: 10px;
    border-color: #000;
    border-top: 1px solid;
}

li:last-child
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

li:hover
{
    border-color: #f00;
}

li:hover + li
{
    border-top-color: #f00;
}
```

Basically, each element in the list of hoverable elements gets a `border-top`. The last element gets both a `border-top` and a `border-bottom`. When you hover over an element, you change its `border-color` and the `border-top-color` of the element directly after it.

The benefit of this method over some others is that it doesn't require hacking your HTML to make the borders show up the way you want. The disadvantage is that IE8 does not support `:last-child`.

Comment: +1 for pure css. just beware that IE8 does not support :last-child

Answer (score 4):

It really depends how you have created the lines. If they are top borders of DIVs (guessing by your title) you could try something like this;

```
div:hover {
    border-color: blue;
}
div:hover + div { /* the div following the hovered div */
    border-color: blue;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/frw2n/

Comment: This wouldn't work because the border element for the one before will not change to blue.

Comment: That depends. If the markup is `<div><a>Link1</a></div><div><a>Link 2</a></div>` then it's fine.

Comment: @pzin the one before what? as stated, here i assume the lines are top-borders

Comment: If they are top borders, then there is no effect on border for the one before. +1

Comment: Yep. That's what I meant. Seeing as `+` is just a descendant brother selector.

Comment: There is no three borders in total. I think that's OP used equal sign to represent changed border.

Comment: @xec, but I agree with you, maybe we are misunderstood each other (my english is not so good)

Comment: I know what you meant. I must say the question is a bit confusing, because he ask for *affect next div aswell* (in that case `+` is obviously right) but in the explanation he *draws* borders for the before hovered element.

Comment: In my first comment, i was talking to @pzin.

Comment: I think was my fault thinking the double lines was meaning to affect to ascendant element also. :/ So obviously using `+` is what he asked for. Anyway, +1. Sorry.

Comment: Kind of gross because it requires an extra element. Any kind of styling of the elements in the list that affects the geometry carries with it a risk of making this hack turn visually ugly. The only ways around it are to put an inline `display: none` on that element (please don't) or to use the `:last-child` or `:first-child` pseudo-class, which if you are using, you might as well use to avoid the need for the hack altogether.

Comment: @QuinnStrahl indeed, it would be easier to find a proper solution if we knew more about the issue at hand (the question is lacking any code, at all) - the extra tag was simply for demonstration purposes, my suggestion is just trying to show a possible use for the immediate sibling combinator.

Answer (score 0):

For the top and bottom borders, you can try putting the links in a div and give all these divs the same class name and style that class like so:

```
.classname:hover
{
    border-top:1px dotted blue;
    border-bottom:1px dotted blue;
}
```

If I understand you correctly...

Hope this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**markup:**

```
<a href='#'>link1 </a>
<a href='#'>link2 </a>
<a href='#'>link3 </a>
```

**CSS:**

```
a
{
    padding:20px;
    width:100px;
    border:1px Solid #CCC;
}
a:hover
{
    border:1px Solid Red;
}
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbekA/)